# Rails Record Not Found Error Couldn't find Workout without an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have looked at many similar posts, but can't seem to get rid of this `record not found` error I get when trying to use my `destroy` method.  The two models in question are `workouts.rb` and `exercises.rb`.  A workout `has_many` exercises.

The error I'm getting is `Couldn't find Workout without an ID` on the third line of the below code from my `exercises_controller`:

```
def destroy
  @workout = Workout.friendly.find(params[:workout_id])
  exercise = @workout.exercises.find(params[:id])
```

My `exercise.rb` model is:

```
class Exercise < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :workout
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :reports
  validates :user, presence: true
end
```

My `workout.rb` model is:

```
class Workout < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :exercises
  has_many :reports
  validates :user, presence: true
end
```

And my full `exercises_controller` is:

```
class ExercisesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @exercises = Exercise.all
  end

  def new
    @exercise = Exercise.new
  end

  def create
    @workout = Workout.friendly.find(params[:workout_id])
    exercise = @workout.exercises.new(exercise_params)
    exercise.user = current_user

    if exercise.save
      flash[:notice] = "Results saved successfully."
      redirect_to [@workout]
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Results failed to save."
      redirect_to [@workout]
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @workout = Workout.friendly.find(params[:workout_id])
    exercise = @workout.exercises.find(params[:id])

    if exercise.destroy
      flash[:notice] = "Exercise was deleted successfully."
      redirect_to [@workout]
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Exercise couldn't be deleted. Try again."
      redirect_to [@workout]
    end
  end

  private

  def exercise_params
    params.require(:exercise).permit(:name, :needs_seconds, :needs_weight, :needs_reps)
  end

  def authorize_user
    exercise = Exercise.find(params[:id])
    unless current_user == current_user.admin?
      flash[:alert] = "You do not have permission to create or delete an exercise."
      redirect_to [exercise.workout]
    end
  end
end
```

My routes are simple:

```
resources :workouts
resources :exercises
```

EDIT:

The code calling the deletion is:

```
<%= link_to "Delete #{exercise.name}", exercise_path, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

Any ideas where this error is coming from?

Comment: What are the `params` that are coming to the `destroy` action?

Comment: can you paste code, from which request are coming here

Comment: @Mukesh, I added the ERB code to my original post.

Comment: path should be like this exercise_path(workout_id: id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't do much for you without the code. However, a common mistake would be to forget the `:id` on the route.

Is see that you auto-generate them with Rails, so it's easy to forget that a destroy action for your exercice resource would be a `DELETE` action on `/exercises/:id`

Mind the `id` in the route !

Moreover, reading you controller, it looks like you expect a `workout_id`, then the correct routing for that would be :

```
resources :workouts do
    resources :exercices
end
```

Which is gonna enable to have these routes :

```
GET    /workouts/:workout_id/exercices(.:format)          exercices#index
POST   /workouts/:workout_id/exercices(.:format)          exercices#create
GET    /workouts/:workout_id/exercices/new(.:format)      exercices#new
GET    /workouts/:workout_id/exercices/:id/edit(.:format) exercices#edit
GET    /workouts/:workout_id/exercices/:id(.:format)      exercices#show
PATCH  /workouts/:workout_id/exercices/:id(.:format)      exercices#update
PUT    /workouts/:workout_id/exercices/:id(.:format)      exercices#update
DELETE /workouts/:workout_id/exercices/:id(.:format)      exercices#destroy
GET    /workouts(.:format)                                workouts#index
POST   /workouts(.:format)                                workouts#create
GET    /workouts/new(.:format)                            workouts#new
GET    /workouts/:id/edit(.:format)                       workouts#edit
GET    /workouts/:id(.:format)                            workouts#show
PATCH  /workouts/:id(.:format)                            workouts#update
PUT    /workouts/:id(.:format)                            workouts#update
DELETE /workouts/:id(.:format)                            workouts#destroy
```

Mind the `workout_id` in the nested routes.

So if you have the workout with `id = 3`, for exercice with `id = 23`, you'll be able to send a `DELETE` on `/workouts/3/exercices/23` and in your `ExercicesController`, you will have access to these two values :

```
params[:id] = 23
params[:workout_id] = 3
```

Like you expect, I think.

I went overboard, hope it was useful. I tried to enrich my answer based on your code.

Comment: I augmented my original post with the ERB code.  Sorry for such an obvious oversight.

Comment: I did originally have nested routes like this, but I ended up un-nesting them because it was causing more problems than it was solving.

Comment: Either way, in your deletion button, for your path, you need to specify the `id`, like this : `exercise_path(id: exercise.id)`

Comment: Or if you prefer, to let Rails do the work, `exercise_path(exercise)`

Comment: I tried both of these, but neither changes the error.